# Using ScrollTop in FlexBox does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox, scrolltop

nav, main, footer, there are 3 tags. I applied them to FlexBox :

```
body {
  color: #ddd;
  font-family: Gotham;
  background: url(../assets/body-background.png);
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

everything looks so good. but things are getting worse after that

I have the following code in my script file (using jQuery):

```
$('.scroll-top').click(function () {
  $('body').animate({
     scrollTop: 0
  }, 1000);
})
```

but the page scrolling animation is not working

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcode/yex3199w/)

```js
$('a').click(function(){
 $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
})
```

```css
nav{
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
}
main{
  height:800px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
footer{
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main{
  flex: 1;
}
a{
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>nav content</nav>
<main>main content</main>
<a href="javascript:;">scroll top</a>
<footer>footer content</footer>
```

Comment: editted question https://jsfiddle.net/vcode/yex3199w/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its working fine in Chrome, but not working in Firefox. For the scroll to work in Firefox, you must use *scrollTop* on `html`:

```
$('body,html').animate({
  scrollTop: 0
}, 1000);
```

Also the `main` won't take the 800px you have assigned to it in Firefox. Change `flex: 1` to `flex: 1 1 800px` for same behaviour cross-browser.

See demo below:

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
nav {
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
}

main {
  height: 800px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

footer {
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 800px; /* NEW */
}

a {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>nav content</nav>
<main>main content</main>
<a href="javascript:;">scroll top</a>
<footer>footer content</footer>
```

Comment: I do not actually use 800px for the main tag. I wrote it easily 800px. I do not actually use 800px for the main tag. I wrote it easily 800px. I tried and tried the script code you suggested. thank you so much.

Comment: Just adding the "html," before the jquery tag fixed it for me. Thank you!